# UPDATE user record by removing specific @ string & adding exactly 3 random digits

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is I want to find user records containing email

`Select * from user where username like "%@%";`

And then break the field at `@`, set 1st part as username & concat random number of 3 digits

For Example:

userxyz@gmail.com

should be : userxyz123, userxyz999, userxyz239 etc

so far i've created

```
UPDATE DB.users 
SET 
    username =  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, "@", 1), ABS(RAND() * 100))
WHERE
    username like "%@%"
```

but the issue is Random number is generated with up to 10 decimal points & `@` is not removed. userxyz@34.815057492642715

Thanks

Comment: `LPAD(FLOOR(RAND()*999), 3, '0')`

Answer (score 0):

It depends to some extend on what you want the user names to look like.  Do you want `user034` or `user34`?  Do you want numbers with leading zero or just values from 100 to 999?

The basic answer to your question is:

```
UPDATE DB.users 
    SET username =  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '@', 1),
                           FLOOR(ABS(RAND() * 1000))
                          )
    WHERE username like '%@%';
```

If you want the padding to exactly three characters:

```
    SET username =  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '@', 1),
                           LPAD(FLOOR(ABS(RAND() * 1000)), 3, '0')
                          )
```

If you wanted to dispense with leading `0`s:

```
    SET username =  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(username, '@', 1),
                           LPAD(FLOOR(ABS(100 + RAND() * 900)), 3, '0')
                          )
```